# creating sub-accounts accounts without exposing the master account private key

Tags: nearprotocol

Creating main account in near protocol requires a deposit. This can make onboarding difficult for app users. Creating sub-accounts are free, but what is the best way to do it without exposing the master account private key. Should I store the private key of master account in a server and allow users to create the account?

[Near api js](https://near.github.io/near-api-js/classes/_account_creator_.accountcreator.html) allows creating account, will that be possible doing using python, or calling json rpc from python?

Answer (score 3):

Another option that don't require your `FullAccessKey` is creating sub-accounts via a contract deployed to your account.

If you are using rust and [`near-sdk-rs`](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs) you should call the fuction [`create_account`](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/ab5c01ca4c61a6414484b69302b84e5ce3113f2f/near-sdk/src/promise.rs#L230). This is an example from the docs about how to use it:

```rust
Promise::new("bob_near".to_string())
  .create_account()
  .transfer(1000)
  .add_full_access_key(env::signer_account_pk());
```

This is the code of a contract that handles sub-account creation:

```rust
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use near_sdk::{env, near_bindgen, AccountId, Balance, Promise};

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Registry {}

#[near_bindgen]
impl Registry {
    #[init]
    pub fn init() -> Self {}

    #[payable]
    pub fn create_account(&mut self, name: AccountId, balance: Balance) -> Promise {
        let target = format!("{}.{}", name, env::current_account_id());

        // Here add some rules in case you don't want everyone
        // to claim any unclaimed sub-account.

        Promise::new(target)
            .create_account()
            .transfer(balance)
            .add_full_access_key(env::signer_account_pk())
    }
}
```

To create any sub-account any user can call the function `create_account` function in the contract passing the name of the sub-account (only the prefix before the dot) and the balance that will be used to initialize the account.

This will work even if the main account doesn't have any `FullAccessKey` anymore.